# exchange 2003 owa include username/password in a url string

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I have an existing Microsoft Exchange 2003 OWA installation that is currently being used:

https://mail.mydomain.com/exchange/

I have a web application that uses session variables to store username and password.  What is the proper syntax to construct a URL string that includes the username and password without requiring them to login?  I am thinking it would be something like

https://mail.mydomain.com/exchange/?username=user&password=pass

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to pass credentials in clear text

Comment: the web app is on the intranet behind a firewall...if somebody is scooping passwords then we have much bigger problems than clear text passwords.  any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OWA isn't going to accept the creds this way. If you're using Forms Based Auth, you can either fabricate the cookie for it or do a post and simulate the user logging in to get the cookie. If it's using Windows Integrated Auth, you don't have much in the way of options. Basic authentication works by putting creds in HTTP headers so you could potentially simulate this.